# Why nextjs13 router.push is slower than Link

Tags: next.js

I'm new to nextjs and am creating a personal blog to test things out.
When I click on a post, it takes me to the address of the post and I can see the post. Is there a big difference in speed between using router.push to create a button and using

, why is there such a big difference in speed?

Overwhelmingly, router.push is slower.
How is this related?

Comment: Because the link component prefetches pages, this means that the page the user would click next is already ready and rendered. If the page is static, link will probably be just as fast as the `router.push` function. Note that the router also has a `prefetch` method.